# Export excel file from database through browser using mvc

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, export-to-excel

I want to export sql table data to excel file on client pc 'through  browser' using mvc.Here's what i use:

```
public class ManagementController : Controller
{
  public void ExportitemToExcel()
    {        
        try
        {              
            dt = SqlHelper.LoadTable("SM_GetAllItems", sql);
            if (dt != null && dt.Rows.Count > 0)
            {                   
                ExportToExcel(dt);
            }
        }
        catch
        { throw; }       
    }
```

Here is export to excel method:

```
 private void ExportToExcel(DataTable dt)
    {
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application excel;
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook worKbooK;
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet worKsheeT;
        excel = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
        excel.Visible = false;
        excel.DisplayAlerts = false;
        worKbooK = excel.Workbooks.Add(Type.Missing);

        worKsheeT = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)worKbooK.ActiveSheet;
        worKsheeT.Name = "Inventory";

        //Create an Excel workbook instance and open it from the predefined location
        // Excel.Workbook excelWorkBook = excel.Workbooks.Open(@"E:\Org.xlsx");
        // Excel.Worksheet excelWorkSheet = excelWorkBook.Sheets.Add();
        //excelWorkSheet.Name = dt.TableName;

        for (int i = 1; i < dt.Columns.Count + 1; i++)
        {
            worKsheeT.Cells[1, i] = dt.Columns[i - 1].ColumnName;
        }

        for (int j = 0; j < dt.Rows.Count; j++)
        {
            for (int k = 0; k < dt.Columns.Count; k++)
            {
                worKsheeT.Cells[j + 2, k + 1] = dt.Rows[j].ItemArray[k].ToString();
            }

        }
        string fastExportFilePath = "C:/" + "Inventory" + ".xlsx";

        if (System.IO.File.Exists(fastExportFilePath))
        {
            System.IO.File.Delete(fastExportFilePath);
        }

        worKbooK.SaveAs(fastExportFilePath);
        worKbooK.Close();
        excel.Quit();
```

This creates file but silently i.e not through browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't save the excel directly to the client's pc. What you can do is to save the excel to the server and share it with clients to download.

You can modify your ExportToExcel method to return the generated file name which you'll use to open your excel file.

```
private string ExportToExcel(DataTable dt)
{
  //your code goes here
  return fastExportFilePath
}
```

Javascript

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
//Check if the hidden field has a value. (Excel was generated)
if ($('#hdnFileName').val() != '')
{
 var url = "Full path to your file" + $('#hdnFileName').val();

                window.location.assign(url)
}
});
```